# How to bind two arrays using Input/Output Angular?

Tags: angular

A component gets (via @Input()) 2 arrays: "users"

```
[{Id: 1, Name: 'One'}, {Id: 2, Name: 'Two'}, {Id: 3, Name: 'Three'}]
```

and "selectedUsers":

```
[{Id: 2, Name: 'Two'}]
```

and outputs items on a page:
One
Two
Three

"Two" - is highlighted as it is contained in array "selectedUsers". 
How to add item from "users" array to "selectedUsers" and vice versa by click (and highlight clicked item)?

Parent component:

```
users = [
    {Id: 1, Name: 'One'}, 
    {Id: 2, Name: 'Two'}, 
    {Id: 3, Name: 'Three'}
];

usersSelected = [
    {Id: 2, Name: 'Two'}
];
```

HTML:

```
<app-item (*ngFor="let u of users", [user]="u")></app-item>
```

Child component:

```
@Input() user;
isActive: boolean = false;
toggleClass(){
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
}
```

HTML

```
<p [class.active]="isActive" (click)="toggleClass()">{{user.Name}}</p>
```

Here's another try but it should be done with @Input/@Output:
https://plnkr.co/edit/cjaij4aQuvN4Tk4ZE0ez?p=preview

Comment: (*ngFor="let u of users", [user]="u") is totaly impossible.
First : if you want to update isActive in parent you only need: one input "isActive" that you will update and one output "isActiveChange" (EventEmiter), that you will emit each time you update isActive. the "Change" end is really important ! you will be able to use with [(isActive)]="whereYouWantPutBoolean"

Comment: Why is (*ngFor="let u of users", [user]="u") is totaly impossible? Then how to output list?

Comment: Why do you need 2 arrays? Just extend the user type with a property named `selected` of type `boolean` (true/false). That is cleaner/easier to use then copying/removing users between the 2 arrays. Also I do not believe that is valid template syntax in your html.

Comment: I'm looking at your plunker and you have types error. To you use tslint ? 
selectedPerson must bu an array of person (as you init it in constructor) so there is no name on the array and you can not do "this.selectedPerson = person;" but you can do "this.selectedPerson.push(person);"

Comment: You can only refer to EventEmiter in (). `*ngFor="let u of users", [user]="u"` is not a reference so it's an invalid syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to use two arrays and a parent and child component:

https://plnkr.co/edit/uEKeMRMpLnoR49clxCfo?p=preview

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-parent',
  template: `
    <my-child [users]="users" [selected]="selected" ></my-child>
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent {
  public users = ['one', 'two', 'three'  ];
  public selected = [];
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-child',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let user of users">
      <p [ngClass]="{ selected: isSelected(user) }" (click)="clickOnUser(user)">{{user}}</p>
    </div>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .selected {
      color: red;
    }
  `]
})
export class ChildComponent {

  @Input()
  public users: string[];

  @Input()
  public selected: string[];

  public isSelected(user) {
    return this.selected.indexOf(user) !== -1;
  }

  public clickOnUser(user) {
    if (this.selected.indexOf(user) !== -1) {
      this.selected.splice(this.selected.indexOf(user), 1);
    } else {
      this.selected.push(user);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Your variant is very close to the desired result! Could you make a hint, how to add @Input/@Output here? I've added @Input() user;
    @Input() selected;
    @Input() isSelected;
    @Input() clickOnUser; to child, added publics to parent, but there's an error "isSelected  is not a function"

Comment: An additional hint. If you don't want to pass the functions `clickOnUser` and `isSelected` to the child component. Then it is not required to add `@Input()`

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need 2 arrays? Just extend the user type with a property named `selected` of type `boolean` (true/false). That is cleaner/easier to use then copying/removing users between the 2 arrays.

```
users = [
    {Id: 1, Name: 'One', IsSelected: false}, 
    {Id: 2, Name: 'Two', IsSelected: true}, 
    {Id: 3, Name: 'Three', IsSelected: false}
];
```

This allows any component that is used for rendering a user in the array to update the `IsSelected` property directly.

```
@Input() user;
get isActive(): boolean {return this.user.IsSelected;}

toggleClass(){
    this.user.IsSelected = !this.user.IsSelected;
}
```

---

*Also I do not believe that is valid template syntax in your html.*

Comment: Just be aware that you mutate objects.

Comment: The thing is that we should bind 2 arrays, that's why here are 2 arrays.